# Is it possible for a site to spoof referer header

Tags: javascript, security

So obviously a request header can be spoofed via client side, by any Extension/AV/Firewall/Browser settings etc...

My question is: 
Can a site owner `bad.com` can create an iframe `mywidget.php`, and i will see a spoofed referer header `good.com`.

The spoofing will be done by the site owner, eg: server, and not by an actual client software listed on top.

Two points:

1. I am talking about a diffrent referer `good.com` and not an empty one.
2. Obviously **exclude** ajax requests.
3. If it is actually possible - Content security policy, can be a solution. but i don't want to add every single domain to it's header value.

Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately the *client* decides which header to send, the site owner has absolutely no say in the matter. That said, the question is whether a site owner could set up some clever redirects which would make the client decide on an unexpected referer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, such possibility does exist and a lot of "good.com"-kind of sites struggle to fix such an issue.

Imagine that for some reasons, "good.com" has a redirecting gateway for statistical or other well-reasoned purposes. For example, this allows "good.com" to measure how many times its users go out to different sites.

Now on a "bad.com" user sees an `iframe`, or just a button that somehow navigates them to a URL like that: `good.site.example/redirect?to=www.thirdparty.com`. And that page on a URL redirects user to `www.thirdparty.com` in a way that preserves a Referer.

So basically yes, the `Referer` HTTP header is not something to depend on in terms of security.

Comment: Thanks,
Just to be sure, you meant that `www.thirdparty.com` is my domain, as on the question `mywidget.php`

Comment: Yes, `www.thirdparty.com` is your domain, `good.com` is some big web portal, likely with user-generated content, and `bad.com` wants you to see the user as if they came from `good.com`.

Answer (score 3):

Not spoof, but if there are any [open redirect vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet)  on your site then they could pass the request through those (as [Andrew Sklyarevsky points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996875/413180)).

The other thing to beware of is parsing bugs.

e.g. if you're checking for referer as `http://good.example.com` using a poor URL parsing technique, then an attacker may try a request from their page such as

`http://bad.example.com?http://good.example.com`

to your page which satisfies your validation.

Also note that some users have privacy extensions enabled which withhold the referer header, which could hinder your security checks and leave them vulnerable or unable to use your site depending on how you implement it.