# How can I spoof the request from client to server?

Tags: javascript, html, express, server, proxy

I want to spoof the request from the client so the server accepts the requests.

##### The server only accepts requests from localhost, is it possible to spoof the requests from the client, so when the server receives the request headers they contain localhost?

I have read that curl or a proxy server might work, but I have not been able to make it work.

> I tried using my public IP but it only works from my wifi, when trying to use the client from another wifi the server rejects the requests.

Comment: No, this time I am asking specifically on how to spoof the request from client not how to deep clone the window object.

Comment: What part of the request are you trying to spoof? Is it the referer?

Comment: yes, the referer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for a site to spoof referer header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996579/is-it-possible-for-a-site-to-spoof-referer-header)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried but the connection is rejected by the http://good.example.com webpage. I tried with the right url inside an iframe by the way, the url that accepts the requests not good.example.

Comment: What makes you think that good.example.com is checking the referer (instead of the client IP for example)?

Comment: I tried this as mentioned in the link shared by @evolutionxbox: http://bad.example.com?http://good.example.com and good.site.example/redirect?to=www.thirdparty.com but the referrer does not change with the first option and good.example rejects the request in the second option.